# PDF reader suggestion in Ubuntu 17.10 (that supports wayland session)

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, 17.10

The default PDF reader in Ubuntu doesn't support bookmarking pages, writing notes and underlining text. Because I need this I am looking for another PDF reader.

I was trying to install Adobe Reader but it did not work. Anyone got any good PDF readers to suggest, or a working procedure to get Adobe Reader installed on 17.10?

Comment: Okular was the software I needed!

Answer (score 1):

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/okular/

> "Okular is a universal document viewer with support for advanced
>   document features, such as annotations, forms, and embedded files."